# How to profile a java application in debug mode with JProfiler

Tags: java, eclipse, jprofiler

I would like to get a memory snapshot at a very specific point in time, i.e. at my break point.

But I can't seem to find the necessary buttons/configuration to start the profiling in debug mode.

Using Eclipse and JProfiler 7.

Edit: More info:

[image]

Comment: Dear @JoeriHendrickx, this is a valid question and I have given a clear answer. Please help me reopen it. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @MichaelDodd, this is a valid question and I have given a clear answer. Please help me reopen it. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @EdwardRuchevits, this is a valid question and I have given a clear answer. Please help me reopen it. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @rkosegi, this is a valid question and I have given a clear answer. Please help me reopen it. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @CodeChimp, this is a valid question and I have given a clear answer. Please help me reopen it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

Sessions->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

in the JProfiler GUI to get the VM parameter for profiling and add that to the VM parameters of the debug run configuration in eclipse. When the run configuration is started, it will wait for a connection from the JProfiler GUI.

Comment: Thanks. I added the -agentpath parameter (see screenshot), but when launching, it does not wait for the JProfiler GUI. Not sure if this was the correct place to configure the parameter.

Comment: You have to add it to VM parameters, not to the program arguments.